# How to get the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}(1/2)^{\log \left(\log \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

For $$\log \left(\log \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{2}\log \left(\log \left(x^2\right)\right)^2$$
where $x\to 0$.

How to get the limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}(1/2)^{\log \left(\log \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this as $\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac t {2^{\log \log t}}$. Then put $s=\log \log t$ to write it as $\lim_{s \to \infty} \frac {e^{(e^{s})}} {2^{s}}$. Use the fact that $e^{x} >x$ for $x >0$ to see that the limit is $\infty$.

Comment: But how about the $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}(1/2)^{(\log x+ \log \left(\log \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right))^2}$ if I add a $\log x$ to the exponent and get it square? Is it 0 now?

Answer (score 1):

Set $1/x^2=e^y,$ $y \rightarrow \infty$.

$e^y(1/2)^{\log y} > e^y(1/2)^y=(e/2)^y$.

Take the limit.

Note: $\log y <y$ , and $e/2>1.$

Answer (score 1):

You can set $x^2 = e^{-u}$ and consider $u \rightarrow \infty$.

Now, the limit becomes

$$\frac{1}{x^2}(1/2)^{\log \left(\log \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)} \stackrel{x^2=e^{-u}}{=}\frac{e^u}{u^{\log 2}}\stackrel{u\to \infty}{\rightarrow} \infty$$