# How to get the $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}(1/2)^{\bigg(\log x+ \log \left(\log \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)\bigg)^2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

Based on my previous question: [[How to get the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}(1/2)^{\log \left(\log \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3532552/how-to-get-the-limit-lim-x-to-0-frac1x21-2-log-left-log-left-fr/3532558?noredirect=1#comment7265364_3532558) ]

How to get the limit

> $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}(1/2)^{\bigg(\log x+ \log \left(\log \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)\bigg)^2}$$ 
>   as $x\to 0$.

I feel like $\log x >> \log\log x$ when $x\to 0$, so it is just 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}(1/2)^{\big(\log x\big)^2}$$

Is it $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: As in your previous question [[How to get the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}(1/2)^{\log \left(\log \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3532552/how-to-get-the-limit-lim-x-to-0-frac1x21-2-log-left-log-left-fr/3532558?noredirect=1#comment7265364_3532558) ] you can put $t=\frac 1 {x^{2}}$ first and then put $t=e^{s}$ to see that the limit is $0$.

Compare with $\lim _{s \to \infty} \frac {e^{s}} {e^{\frac 1  4s^{2} \ln 2}}$ which is clearly $0$.

Comment: Why did you post two separate questions almost at the same time for very similar textbook questions ? You should grooup them or at least give a link in the second to the first one.

Comment: @JeanMarie Since I try to modify the limit to get my wanted limit. Sorry about that. I will group them. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy After simplifying this limit following yours, we have $e^s(1/2)^{(-s/2+\log s)^2}$. Do you mean $e^s$ tends to zero faster?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Well, if I let $s=\log\log (1/x^2)$, I get the $e^{e^s}/ 2^{(-e^s/2+s)^2}$ which may tend to $\infty$ as $s\to \infty$?

Comment: @BobOakley I have added one more line. Do not got to $e^{e^{s}}$. Just stay with $e^{s}$ by substituting $t=e^{s}$ as  I said in my answer. You are complicating things by taking $s =\ln \ln t$.